# django default registration module takes unique username but same email

Tags: python, django, email, django-authentication, django-registration

I am using the django default registration module to signup users. 
What the module is doing, it is registering users with different username but same email. 
How would I be able to send them forgot_password email if it is doing so ??

I wrote this in my views.py so that same email doesnt get registered but this is also not working. users are still getting registered with same email.

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                user_present = User.objects.get(username=form.username)
            except:
                user_present = None
            if user_present:
                messages.error(request, 'Username already taken')
                args = {}
                args.update(csrf(request))
                args['form'] = MyRegistrationForm()
                return render_to_response('register.html',args)
            else:
                try:
                    user_present = User.objects.get(email=form.email)
                except:
                    user_present = None
                if user_present:
                    messages.error(request, 'Your email is already registered.')
                    args = {}
                    args.update(csrf(request))
                    args['form'] = MyRegistrationForm()
                    return render_to_response('register.html',args)
                else:
                    form.save()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register_success')
        else:
            args = {}
            args.update(csrf(request))
            args['form'] = MyRegistrationForm()
            messages.error(request, 'There were errors in the form. Please fill again.')
            return render_to_response('register.html',args)
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = MyRegistrationForm()
    return render_to_response('register.html',args)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Is there any way to add unique=True like this ? :

```
email = forms.EmailField(required=True,unique=True)
```

Comment: What exactly is not working with the code? Try adding some print statements to see where it is going wrong. For a start, the form probably doesn't have a username attribute, so you should access `form.cleaned_data['username']` instead.

Comment: I have made my own form with email field. Please check the question again. I have added the code there.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are using incorrect values for `username` and `email`. You should get them from form like this: `form.cleaned_data['username']` and `form.cleaned_data['email']`. Also I suggest to put this validation into Form itself. Read about `clean_fieldname` methods [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute). One more thing: you don't need any uniqueness test for `username` cause it's by default defined as `unique=True` so just test for email:

```
class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    # your code here
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if email:
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                raise forms.ValidationError('Your email is not unique.')
        return email
```

Your view now is gonna look much simpler without these uniqueness tests.